# How can i push the content when sidenav materialize is open?

Tags: jquery, nav, materialize

I want to push the contents when I open the sidenav, or to be able to execute a function when I close the sidenav.

I use materialize for sidenav.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

This is my code with materialize.

```html
<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
      <li><a href="#!">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse show-on-large"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
```

Comment: Please show us at least a litte bit of your code...

Comment: Sorry friend, I already edit my ask.